# Jenkins - Email-ext plugin display name of job in email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

Is there an easy way to include the display name of the job in the email subject?

Maybe there is an environment variable for this?

I know it should be possible because the default functionality (email notification) in jenkins already provides this information in the email subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct environemnt variable which I was looking for is

> $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME

The display name of the current build, which is something like "#153" by default.

Thanks at @maniframer to provide the link for getting more built-in environments.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You can use the built-in environment `JOB_NAME`, other available environments you can use are like `BUILD_STATUS`, `BUILD_NUMBER`, etc.

```
[${BUILD_STATUS}]${JOB_NAME} Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

[image]

As always, you can go to http://your-jenkins-host/env-vars.html/ to get more built-in environments.