# How to set the Jenkins build job status as as the Default Subject of email using Email Extension

Tags: jenkins

I am using https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/ using  below code I managed to send  code changes in subject body .

Changes:

```
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\"", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}
```

Now my requirement is to pass the build job status as pass or failed in the default subject itself .
Can I do it without using a pipeline?
[image]

Subject
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on anwer of mainframer  [Jenkins - Email-ext plugin display name of job in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772347/jenkins-email-ext-plugin-display-name-of-job-in-email)

I was able to solve this . To add bit of a clarity.

Default Subject- [${BUILD_STATUS}]${JOB_NAME} Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}

To see more more built-in environments.
http://your-jenkins-host/env-vars.html/
Example-
http://100.10.10.10:8080/env-vars.html/

[image]